# Advanced mapping of JSON in Azure Data Factory - some guidance requested

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to map a JSON document (sensor data) into a more meaningful representation using Mapping Dataflows. However, hard time getting this to work and would really appreciate some insight/recommendations on how to solve the following:

The input is

[image: JSON Input]

What I would like to end up with is the following:

[image: Desired output]

Any pointers as to how this can be implemented are more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using the `Copy activity` and then `split` function in `Derived Column` transformation in Azure Data Factory.

1. Use the `copy activity` to read the JSON file as source and in sink, use SQL database to store the data as table. In `Mapping` tab, Import the schema and map the JSON records to the corresponding column names. Refer this third-part tutorial for guidance - https://sqlkover.com/dynamically-map-json-to-sql-in-azure-data-factory/
2. Finally, use the `Data Flow` activity and choose the SQL table as source now which you have used as sink above.

- Select the Derived Column transformation.
- Use `split` function.
- Add the column which will take the split values which you want to split as shown below.

[image]

- Use `split(<column_name_to_split>, '_')` function to split the column on with `_` delimiter. Change `<column_name_to_split>` to the name of column you cant to split. Refer image below.

[image]

Preview the data to check the result.

Comment: Thanks for this input. I will try your approach using SQL as a intermediate step.

Comment: Sure. Do let me know if you face any issue.